# How do I add a new font to a fpdf?

Tags: fonts, addition, fpdf

How can I add the Gotham-book font to fpdf. Most explanations are unclear and very difficult to understand.  I need an example.  Please can someone assist?

Answer (score 29):

Nevermind
Got my answer

Go to
http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/

Convert your .ttf file

Download the .php and the .z file

Add these files to the following folder:
fpdf/font
(This is the default folder structure that you need to download in order for your fpdf to work)

This is the code I have used in my file:

```
$fpdf->AddFont('Gotham','','Gotham-Book.php');
    $fpdf->SetFont('Gotham','',11);
```

Comment: You can alter that path with `define('FPDF_FONTPATH', "yourPath");` but still you have to add all font definition files there...

Answer (score 12):

I was also stuck with this error,
@Janinekey's answer is right but I didn't find how to add variants of a font.
[This article](http://www.asudahlah.com/2017/11/create-add-and-use-custom-font-in-php.html) explains this process really well too.

I will explain the whole process in steps.

**Step 1.** Download all the variant's of your font (Regular, Bold, Italic, Bold-Italic)

**Step 2.** Convert all the fonts to `font-name.php` and `font-name.z` from this [link](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/)

**Step 3.** Copy all *.php and *.z files in fonts/ folder which is in root directory of fpdf.php. [You can rename *.php files, but don't rename *.z once you converted them from ttf].

**Step 4.** 
Use this code to import the font into your pdf:

```
//Importing Font and it's variations
$fpdf->AddFont('Gotham','','Gotham-Book.php'); //Regular
$fpdf->AddFont('Gotham','B','Gotham-Book-bold.php'); //Bold
$fpdf->AddFont('Gotham','I','Gotham-Book-italic.php'); //Italic
$fpdf->AddFont('Gotham','BI','Gotham-Book-bold-italic.php'); //Bold_Italic

//Now use it as normal font
$fpdf->SetFont('Gotham','B',11);
```

PS: Font name will be same for different variants. So, make sure you don't change it, otherwise you will treat it as another font completely.

Answer (score 1):

To set the font you can try this snippet:

```
pdf = PDF()
pdf.add_font('Roboto','','path_of_the_.ttf_file',uni=True)
```

and then

```
self.set_font('Roboto', '', 8)
```