# How to Add own Font (Japanese font) in FPDI Library?

Tags: php, laravel, fonts, cjk, fpdi

Here is an example. How can I add the font that I downloaded. How is the process?

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile('sample source of the template.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 210);
$pdf->AddFont('japanesefontnameSample', '', 'japaneseFontsample.ttf', true);
$pdf->SetFont('japanesefontnameSample');
$pdf->SetFontSize(12);
$pdf->SetXY(20, 23);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888281/how-do-i-add-a-new-font-to-a-fpdf) answer.

Comment: successfully load the font but still cannot not recognize the japanese font. it became special character like this "ã‚µãƒ‹ãƒ¼ãƒ©ã‚¤ãƒ•é•’è‘‰ ". do you know any tff font that i can use for japanese character?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using a unicode font? Maybe try some of [these](https://www.freejapanesefont.com/) and see if you still get strange symbols.